# GCS: Is there a request limit for accessing objects?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I just heard that there is a limitation on the Google Cloud Storage, so that you can only access it with a request once per second. I searched through the internet, but didn't find any appropriate answer to this.

Is this right, or can i access it more then once per second? Just want to know for an webapplication i write at the moment, that can up- and download images on the Storage. If there is an limitation, it would cause some delay, if more requests per second are send from different users.

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the 1 a second write limit to ancestor groups in the datastore.Where did you "hear" this from?

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to the limitation that you can update or overwrite *the same object* up to once per second. There's no limit to the number of times you can update across different objects, or to the number of reads you can do to any object.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#object-updates